# I can connect to server using telnet, but can't connect using ftp

Tags: linux, ftp

I have 2 linux PC and remote FTP-server:
From PC_1 I can connect to FTP without any issues. From PC_2 I can ping server, connect via telnet to 21 port, but can't connect using ftp:

```
user@pc2:~$ ftp *.*.*.*
ftp: connect: Connection timed out
```

All network rules for both machines are the same. Some time ago I already connected to server from both PCs. Nothing has changed since. What could be an issue?

Comment: A firewall on the ftp server that allows ftp from PC_1 but not from PC_2 ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, upd my question. I already connected to this server some time ago from both my PCs

Comment: If nothing has changed, I don't have a clue.